# Mac-OSX inside windows 7-Is it possible?

Tags: mac

Is it possible to install  mac-osx inside the windows 7 using virtual box. Heard that the software is bound to certain hardware specifications that only apple hardware can satisfy.I need to install mac-os to practice Objective C.I dont have an apple laptop.Is there any way to install mac-osx in my laptop.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Hackingtosh / OSx86 is what you're looking for.
Stack OverFlow does not discuss this topic because it's illegal to do so.
According to Apple's EULA, OSX can only be installed on “Apple labeled hardware".

Fortunately you can also program Objective-C on Windows:
http://www.gnustep.org/experience/Windows.html

Comment: Is there any commands to run the program in GNUstep on my laptop.I am using mac-osx in office and have installed xcode to practice on objective C.with command + r i could run the program on console to view the output.